# How to restrict some 3 digit company codes from a text field under Company

Tags: validation-rule

we currently have a 'Company Short Name' field under our Company object, and in this field the sales team put a 3 letter abbreviation of the company name.

I would like to stop certain 3 letters being used like dic, fuk and so on.

Is there any easy way to do this ??

Many thanks in advance.
Mike

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a regular expression in a validation rule:

```
REGEX(Company_Short_Name__c, '.*(fuk|dic).*')
```

Just add extra values separated by the "pipe" character. The [`REGEX` function](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_regex.htm&type=5) in validation rule formulas performs case-insensitive matching, I believe.

Comment: Thanks that's sorted it, thank you both.  Appreciate it.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on how many different possibilities there are, the simplest way would be a validation rule.

```
Company_Short_Name__c = "fuk" || Company_Short_Name__c = "dic"
```

Etc...

To check different cases, e.g. DIC or Dic etc., use the `LOWER` function to first switch to lower case.

```
LOWER(Company_Short_Name__c) = "fuk" || LOWER(Company_Short_Name__c) = "dic"
```

Comment: Thank you so much will try it, there's quite a lot to add in about 20 ?

Comment: How do I add more than one line in the code ?